# How to run a python script automatically in Ubuntu 14.04 on reboot

Tags: 14.04, python

I am trying to run a command on reboot. So that every time I restart my Ubuntu 14.04 server it should run automatically. It's a python command.

```
/usr/bin/python /home/shiv/workspace/CustomOpenERP/openerp-8.0/openerp-server -s -c /home/shiv/.openerp-serverrc
```

I kept this command in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file. But it's not working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: keep it in `/etc/rc.local` or preferably in `~/.profile`

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal by <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute following command:

```
sudo -H /etc/rc.local
```

Add the lines given below to the file but before exit 0.

```
sudo /usr/bin/python /home/shiv/workspace/CustomOpenERP/openerp-8.0/openerp-server -s -c /home/shiv/.openerp-serverrc
```

Answer (score 0):

At system reboot, user `shiv` is not logged in

Is `/home/shiv` mounted? Not if you have an encrypted home directory (If `/home/shiv/.Private` is a link to `/home/.ecryptfs/shiv/.Private` you do).

Move (reinstall) the software and data that you have installed underneath `/home/shiv` to the `/usr/local` tree (see `man hier` (`hier - description of the filesystem hierarchy`).

Comment: Hi waltinator. You are right at system reboot shiv user is not logged in. I can't install it again. I am new bie to Ubuntu. So can you please make me understand simply what exactly i have to do to achieve my results.

Comment: Do you have `sudo` access? Type `sudo -l`, and,  when prompted, type YOUR LOGIN PASSWORD. If not, can you get your system administrator to help?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Upstart job for your script: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html